# My server is eating up ram usage

Tags: 18.04, server, samba, zfs, storage

For some reason my storageserver is always eating up ram usage but only to a limited point not where it gets critical to my eyes.

my storageserver is a self made server using an 
intel xeon e5-1620 
32GB ram ddr4 ecc reg
4x segate 10TB hdd exos drives -> raid5 using zfs

services running: 
zfs
samba
prometheus and node exporter for grafana monitoring.
my server is running ubuntu server 18.04.4

When i reboot my server it using up about 800MB while at this very moment it's using roughly around 16GB which is alot more, I already reinstalled the os to avoid any kinds of issues.

I have 2 screenshots from system monitoring and htop. In htop btw i see processes 10 times in the list, Is this for every core? -> if not why is it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZFS uses it's own cache called ARC, rather than the regular Linux page cache. This doesn't show up as "cache" in top, but it works just like the regular cache in the sense that it gets released under memory pressure. That is why you see memory going "missing". If you do

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

you'll see that you get all that memory back (and then your disk reads will be slow again until the caches warm up. By default ZFS ARC is capped at 50% of detected memory, which is why you see the memory usage plateau around 16-17GB.

Regarding your 2nd question, many programs aren't single-threaded, some fork many threads, others many processes. Some kernel processes have a separate instance per CPU thread. That is why you are seeing multiple instances of some processes.

Comment: wow, this was very helpfull thanks, So if I understand you correctly I don't need to worry about my ram usage as this is a normal behaviour of zfs ?

Comment: Yes, perfectly normal, nothing to worry about.